# Understanding about SQL index on DateTime Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, database-indexes

I have about 1 million records. When searching through the date range, it is surprisingly slow. Then I do the google search and someone suggested to do the index on the "DateTime" column. I am not convinced because I always thought index is for O(1) search - which means equality search; and since my query is a date range search, how can it be possible to improve the performance?

But, out of curiosity, I tried anyway and to my surprise, it does improve the performance significantly.

Here is my table

```
tblOrder
--------
OrderId (Primary Key)
CurrencyId
ProductId
...
...
...
OrderDate DATETIME
```

I am using linqtosql and the code is:

```
return (from rec in tblOrders.AsNoTracking()
        where (rec.CurrencyId == CurrencyId) && (rec.OrderDate >= startDate) && (rec.OrderDate < endDate)
        select rec).ToList();
```

I created SQL Index on both `CurrencyId` and `OrderDate`. The result is a huge improvement. My question is, how is it possible? Why do indexes work on ***range search*** (not equal but >= or <=). Can someone explain to me how does SQL index work in regards to date range search?

Thank you...

Comment: *"because I always thought index is for O(1) search "* this train of thought is wrong. If I asked you to list all the "Smith"s in a phone book you wouldn't go back to the start of the book after writing each down; you'd go to the next one without starting again. An RDBMS is no different.

Comment: Also, to ensure an index to be helpful you need to ensure it is covering. Just adding an index on your date time column may not be helpful if you are dealing with other columns in the query too (including in the `SELECT`).

Comment: Index search is independent from datatype. For range search it finds the first element to start from (lower bound) and reads all the row references until the upper bound. But do not forget that column order matters: index on `datefield, idfield` will be slower, because DBMS will check each date for that id

Comment: @Larnu Better to say it depends on how much rows will be selected in comparison to overall rowcount. Single date in this example and field name context should be faster anyway

Comment: @astentx you've missed the point of my comment; I'm saying that an index isnt just just to find a specific row in a database, but can be used to find many.

Comment: @Larnu I was about your second comment. Predicate selectivity and filtered column's position in index (i.e. access type) has more impact than column number accessed. If predicate on indexed column selects few records with between or equality criteria it is a good candidate to use index even for `select *`. But of course indexing is not `fast=true` and should be used with clear understanding of their purpose.

Comment: That's why I state it **may** not be helpful @astentx not "won't be".

Comment: @Larnu, yes, of course, I know about putting the record next if there is a collision. But I just don't understand how will it work for ranges. For example, finding "Smith", it will be converted to "number" (depending on the algorithm used) and hit the "Smith" key right away. But it won't be the case for ranges search, or will it? I just need to understand how the index work so I can be careful on the decision to create indexes

Comment: If you want to ask how indexes work, @Sam , you should be asking about them on [dba.se].

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I have posted the question in Database Administrator...

Answer (score 0):

The index is essentially an ordered list of your index keys with the address of the rows they refer to attached to them. You can use equality conditions to jump to any point of your index relatively quickly by following the for the values you’re searching for. Once you get to this point you continue reading the ordered data until it no longer satisfies your access search. For a range predicate this just means jump to the minimum value in your range and start reading until a value greater than the maximum range value appears.

Answer (score -1):

For this `where` clause:

```
    where (rec.CurrencyId == CurrencyId) && (rec.OrderDate >= startDate) && (rec.OrderDate < endDate)
```

You want a composite index where the first two columns are `(CurrencyId, OrderDate)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes, I did create a composite index. But my question is how does the date index work in regards to range search? (ps. I did **not** downvote)